# Multiple layouts for one ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I have ExpandableListView and I extended BaseExpandableListAdapter for my own adapter. I am having hard times with separators, though. I added to my list of objects that go to the ExpandableListView "separators" to certain positions and I need to display them in the ExpandableListView using different row layouts. Now the problem is, that BaseExpandableListAdapter doesn't have methods getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position) that BaseAdapter does. Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Check the docs harder. Those methods exist for child and group views.

Comment: Can't really find it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildType%28int,%20int%29 ?

Comment: That is wild, it is so unexpectable....getChildViewType would make more sense, I totally overlooked it.

Comment: Yes, I think `getChildViewType` would be a better name.

Comment: Maybe you can write it down as an answer, so I can accept it and close this issue:)

Comment: I've added an answer. I hope it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement those "separators" by providing different `Views` for the position you want. To do this use the :

[`getChildType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildType%28int,%20int%29) and [`getChildTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildTypeCount%28%29) (for different child `Views`) 
[`getGroupType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupType%28int%29) and [`getGroupTypeCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroupTypeCount%28%29) (for different group `Views`)

from the [`BaseExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html) class.